# How do I Send json data from Nodejs to Php within same server ( locally )?

Tags: php, json, node.js

I have a `Nodejs` code with `SSE( Server-Sent-Events )`, here for each event its triggers and give some json data. how can i send a json data to other `PHP` file, without calling any POST URL,

Need to send json data to other php file within the same server.

> NodeJS

```
//including Event Source
var EventSource = require('eventsource');
var request     = require('request'); 

var es  = new EventSource('http://api.xyz.com:8100/update/');

//Listening URL Event Sourse 
es.addEventListener('message', function (e) { 

    //Extract Json
    var extractData =  JSON.parse(e.data); 

    if(extractData.type == 'CALL' )
    {  
       console.log(extractData);

        //you can call a function 
        postDataToAFile(extractData); 

    }
});

//Post Details to same server
function postDataToAFile(SendingDetails)
{ 
    var ServerURL = 'http://api.xyz.com/get_details/';

    request({
        url    : ServerURL,
        method : "POST",
        json   : true,
        body   : SendingDetails
    }, function (error, response, body){
        console.log(body);       
    });
}
```

Above code uses POST URL, instead can we send `Json` data derictly using a file path

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-data. A library to create readable "multipart/form-data" streams. Can be used to submit forms and file uploads to other web applications.

The API of this library is inspired by the XMLHttpRequest-2 FormData Interface.

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');

var form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg'));

var FormData = require('form-data');
var http = require('http');

var form = new FormData();

http.request('http://nodejs.org/images/logo.png', function(response) {
  form.append('my_field', 'my value');
  form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
  form.append('my_logo', response);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data